# async db access between requests on GAE/Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, asynchronous, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to optimize my GAE webapp for latency.

The app has two requests which usually come one after another.

Is it safe to start an async db/memcache request during the first request and then use its results inside the following request?

(I'm aware that the second request might hit another instance. It would be handled as a cache miss)

Comment: Leaving aside the question of safety, how would you propose to do this even?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - simply by keeping a reference in the global namespace.

Comment: By global namespace, do you mean in memory of the instance that happened to handle the first request, decreasing the chance of a win in the cache lottery as traffic increases and caching would be more useful?

Comment: @tesdal - That's right. My assumption is, two requests adjacent in time and space have good chances to end up in the same instance.

Comment: I think you'd be better off if you can calculate or look up a key from the requests and use that for memcached lookup in the second request. You might have to spin off a task queue task to generate the data (to enable quick response to first request). Depending on what problem you're trying to solve (use case, not technical) and what your app looks like, there might be different solutions you could explore, like "materialized view" where you calculate on write, combine into a single request etc and so on.

Comment: Agree with @tesdal... What you are describing seems to be the base use case for memcache. Can you please clarify why you cannot just use memcache?

Comment: @Sologoub - I can and am using memcache, but it isn't for free either (time-wise) and that's why it has async API. Nothing beats RAM :-)

Comment: @tesdal - This two-requests-in-a-row seems like a perfect opportunity to use the async API. Weirdly, it seemed working, so I'm curious about this usage safety.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start an async API call in one request and get its result in another.  The HTTP serving infrastructure will wait for all API calls started in a request to complete before the HTTP response is sent back; the data structure representing the async API call will be useless in the second request (even if it hits the same instance).

You might try Appstats to figure out what API calls your request is making and see if you can avoid some, use memcache for some, or parallellize.

You  might also use NDB which integrates memcache in the datastore API.

Comment: That's what I thought from reading the docs, but the weird thing is, it seems to be working.. Could it be I'm getting my async requests implicitly re-created and sent again during the second request?

Comment: Switching to NDB at the moment :-) Thanks for great work! I wish it was there earlier, so I wouldn't have to implement my own ugly-faking-NDB-hacks.

Comment: I'm sure you are seeing a phantom effect, but without code it is impossible to say what is happening. It is probably not worth investigating,